# Migrating filesystem from a VM to Azure Files

Tags: azure, azure-files, azure-file-share

I have an Azure VM (ubuntu 16.04) which is hosting a lot of files.
I want to migrate this files to Azure Files service.
Furthermore, I have reading microsoft documentation about this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction

My idea is to copy the all files inside the VM to Azure Files.I believe I don't need to do file sync.

So what would be the best way to migrate my existing filesystem to Azure Files? And what would the best way to access them afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best way of migrating your files is by using azcopy (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10). Since you're already running your VM inside Azure, your copy performance should be pretty fast since you're already on the Azure Backbone network. I would recommend enabling Service Endpoints beforehand for improved performance.

After your migration to Azure Files, you can access the files as an SMB share and mount them to your system or via other Tools like Azure Storage Explorer or the Azure Files API.

Best regards,

Theragus

Comment: Thanks. Will try that approach anbd report

Comment: I must use sas authentication right? If so, how can I copy and access files from my file shares, programmatically? I guess I have to extend the token expiry time